# How to update the metadata on an endless non-stop radio stream

Tags: flutter, notifications, audio-streaming

I currently have a code like below.  I need to change it so that it can update all backend notification dynamically without the need of reloading/buffering the stream.

Any thoughts?

```
Future<void> _loadPlaylist() async {
  try {
    DataModel dataModel = await Repository().getChannelData();

    final mediaItems = dataModel.data.channelData
      .map((song) =>
      MediaItem(
        id: song.radioUrl,
        album: Strings.appName,
        title: song.description,
        artist: song.channelName,
        extras: {'url': song.radioUrl},
      ))
      .toList();
    _audioHandler.addQueueItems(mediaItems);
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

Comment: What protocol are you using to stream with?

Comment: it's an icecast v2 stream

Comment: audio_service: ^0.18.0